# Adding the Konik Library to a Maven Webservice Project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

i got an Issue. 
My main problem is, that im not a professional Java developer, instead i'm developing in other languages. I just want to try out some things to get a bit of knowledge.

So i want to develop an Webservice which is using the Konik Library to attach the xml version of an pdf invoice. 
To develop it, i'm using Netbeans with the Glassfish server. 
So when i tried to create an maven web application and created a webservice in it. Until now everything is fine, i can build it and i can deploy it to my Glassfish server and it works.

But now i want to add the Konik Library to it, to start developing some Web Methods with it. 
To achieve it, i read the Documentation on the Konik Website and found these read that its all just to include following dependecies to my project :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.konik</groupId>
    <artifactId>konik</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- pdf plugin to attach/extract invoice data -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.konik</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox-carriage</artifactId>
    <!-- see manual for other pdf carriages -->
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

So i added these two dependencies to my pom.xml file of the Maven Web Application. Instantly after i did that, i got some new entries in my project folder  'Dependencies'. Also i can build the application and got no errors. 
But when i want to run it and try to deploy it on the Glassfish server, i got the error "GlassFish Server 4.1.1, deploy, null, false".

Am i doing something wrong ? Did i forgot something ? 
I know it must be very easy to add an library to an Java Project, but im starting to despair of it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with GlassFish Server. For the deployment of the Maven project. I started using Tomcat server. It is easier to use and customize. I advise you to install your project on Tomcat.

1) Tools -> Plugins -> Available plugins, search for 'tomcat' and install the one named "Java EE Base plugin"

2) Restart Netbeans

3) New project -> Maven -> Web Application -> Apache Tomcat

But the library io.konik was not installed in my project on Tomcat.

I manually added the library to the Maven project.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, i'm using the WildFly Application Server now and it works so far. But i added the library also manually

Comment: Glad to help. Just myself was wondering what it's for library. io.konik for some reason is not put automatically. We have to install it manually.